# Memory management with wasm-bindgen

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I am trying to understand wasm-bindgen memory management and infer correct usage to ensure no memory is leaked.

In [Exporting a struct to JS](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/contributing/design/exporting-rust-struct.html) of the wasm-bindgen documentation, it says:

> The free function is required to be invoked to deallocate resources on the Rust side of things.

However, in [Exported struct types](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/exported-rust-types.html), there is no `namedStruct.free();` after `let namedStruct = return_named_struct(42);`. How does that fit together?